# I want to make a dataset except specific time period

Tags: r

my dataset have time column

```
time
2016-07-29 05:24:00
2016-07-29 05:24:00
2016-07-29 03:56:00
2016-07-29 03:56:00
2016-07-29 03:48:00
2016-07-29 03:48:00
2016-07-29 03:44:00
2016-07-29 03:44:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-30 04:15:00
2016-07-30 04:15:00
2016-07-30 04:15:00
2016-07-30 04:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
...
```

I want to make a dataset except specific time period
If I choose row data except 00:00 ~ 06:00

```
time
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-29 23:00:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
2016-07-30 14:15:00
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extract the 'time' part with `format`, then convert to `POSIXct` (to have the same date), then create another vector of datetime for the '06:00' time, use the logical operator (`>`) and subset the rows.

```
v1 <- as.POSIXct(format(as.POSIXct(df1$time), "%H:%M"), format = "%H:%M")
s2 <- as.POSIXct("06:00", format = "%H:%M")
df1[v1 > s2, , drop=FALSE]
#                 time
#9  2016-07-29 23:00:00
#10 2016-07-29 23:00:00
#11 2016-07-29 23:00:00
#12 2016-07-29 23:00:00
#13 2016-07-29 23:00:00
#14 2016-07-29 23:00:00
#19 2016-07-30 14:15:00
#20 2016-07-30 14:15:00
#21 2016-07-30 14:15:00
#22 2016-07-30 14:15:00
```

Or another `base R` option is

```
df1[as.numeric(gsub(".*\\s+|:.*", "", df1$time)) > 6,, drop= FALSE]
```

Or use `strptime`, extract the `hour` and do the logical condition

```
df1[strptime(df1$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")$hour,]
```

NOTE: We did not use any external packages.

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[hour(time)>6]
#                   time
# 1: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 2: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 3: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 4: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 5: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 6: 2016-07-29 23:00:00
# 7: 2016-07-30 14:15:00
# 8: 2016-07-30 14:15:00
# 9: 2016-07-30 14:15:00
#10: 2016-07-30 14:15:00
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(time = c("2016-07-29 05:24:00", "2016-07-29 05:24:00", 
 "2016-07-29 03:56:00", "2016-07-29 03:56:00", "2016-07-29 03:48:00", 
 "2016-07-29 03:48:00", "2016-07-29 03:44:00", "2016-07-29 03:44:00", 
 "2016-07-29 23:00:00", "2016-07-29 23:00:00", "2016-07-29 23:00:00", 
 "2016-07-29 23:00:00", "2016-07-29 23:00:00", "2016-07-29 23:00:00", 
 "2016-07-30 04:15:00", "2016-07-30 04:15:00", "2016-07-30 04:15:00", 
 "2016-07-30 04:15:00", "2016-07-30 14:15:00", "2016-07-30 14:15:00", 
 "2016-07-30 14:15:00", "2016-07-30 14:15:00")), .Names = "time", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Comment: Why use `strptime` ? It is for converting character representations to datetime. `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct()` is practically just a change of attributes alternatively.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, the dataset I used have character column for 'time' as I was not sure whether the class of the OP's dataset is `POSIXct` or not.

Comment: ah, okay, carry on then! :-P

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hour` from `lubridate`:

```
df[lubridate::hour(df$time) > 6,]
```

assuming `df` is your dataframe and `time` is already in `POSIXct` format

Other options in `base R` suggested by @thelatemail:

```
df[with(as.POSIXlt(df$time), hour > 6),]
```

and

```
df[format(df$time,"%H") > "06",]
```

Comment: in base R, something equivalent like `dat[with(as.POSIXlt(dat$time), hour > 6),]` or `dat[format(dat$time,"%H") > "06",]`

Comment: Go for it! The more the merrier :-)